# Magento 2 : Import product image with sku

Tags: magento2, product-images, import, csv

I have a CSV file product image with SKU, I did import all product SKU in admin but not have an image.
here is the CSV file I need import.
[image]

Comment: Do you need to import images from same domain ir external domain?

Comment: I need an external domain. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Download those images in your domain pub/media folder and then import images....else you have to write own script for that.

Comment: can you reference me write the script for that?

Comment: You can import from external image - https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/data-import-product-images.html#method-2-import-images-from-external-server

Comment: I did read that, but it not clear for me.

Comment: @Ranganathan this doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import product images in `Admin panel->System->Import`.

If the image url is an external link - Make sure the external link folder has permission

Try below screenshot example as your import csv

[image: Import product images csv]

Comment: My file did change follow you're referring https://prnt.sc/pjg69f please check the issue here https://prnt.sc/pjg6ya

Comment: Check you log and update.

Comment: Thank you, it's work.

Comment: Oh...sounds good. Welcome

Comment: Do you have a way to update images only? here is a product I did import follow your way https://prnt.sc/pjh677 It loses all the fields that I have imported. eg: name, price...

Comment: Its strange..I think it is an error...Will check and let you know asap

Comment: Thank you.waiting for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99908/discussion-between-ranganathan-and-michaelha).